# playhouse.pool.MaxConnectionsExceeded: Exceeded maximum connectionsc with multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, peewee

I have data and I want to write my code by dividing them to **4 threads**. For ex:
When I have 100 objects , I will **divide them for 25-25-25-25**. Maybe ,I will have **2 objects** .In this case **two of threads** should work.

I wrote code below

```
for item in all_strategy_ids:
            p1 = threading.Thread(target=self.proccess,args=(item.id,))
            p2 = threading.Thread(target=self.proccess,args=(item.id,))
            p3 = threading.Thread(target=self.proccess,args=(item.id,))
            p4 = threading.Thread(target=self.proccess,args=(item.id,))
            p1.start()
            p2.start()
            p3.start()
            p4.start()
            p1.join()
            p2.join()
            p3.join()
            p4.join()
```

And also , I am using peewee .I added this below peewee connection

```
 max_connections=8,stale_timeout=300,
```

However, I get this error :

```
raise MaxConnectionsExceeded('Exceeded maximum connections.')
playhouse.pool.MaxConnectionsExceeded: Exceeded maximum connections.
```

So,The question is how can I manage this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the connection pool then you need to be sure to *close* connections as soon as you're finished using them.

Since you neglected to share any of the code related to initializing the connections, it's hard to say where the problem is. Just make sure you connect at the start of your thread and close before it returns and you should be fine.

Please read the docs, especially the bold part:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#connection-pool